# friend invitation with GKMatchmakerViewController never shows up

Tags: swift, game-center, gamekit, gkmatchmaker

I basically just followed this tutorial https://www.raywenderlich.com/7544-game-center-for-ios-building-a-turn-based-gametried. Instead of a turned-based game, I was trying to make a peer-to-peer real-time match. Here's my code:

```
    let request = GKMatchRequest()
    request.minPlayers = 2
    request.maxPlayers = 2
    request.defaultNumberOfPlayers = 2
    request.recipientResponseHandler = { player, response in
        // never being called
    }

    let vc = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: request)!
    vc.matchmakerDelegate = self
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

The GKMatchmakerViewController shows up correctly. And it can successfully find a match for me automatically. The only problem is that if I manually add a friend in the player slot and press start, it says it's waiting for the other player forever, but nothing shows up on my friend's phone. I don't even know what should it look like when the invitation happens.

I implemented GKLocalPlayerListener and GKMatchmakerViewControllerDelegate, but `player(_ player: GKPlayer, didRequestMatchWithOtherPlayers playersToInvite: [GKPlayer])` and `player(_ player: GKPlayer, didAccept invite: GKInvite)` are never called.

edit: I didn't see such callback to handle invitation before `matchmakerViewController(_ viewController: GKMatchmakerViewController, didFind match: GKMatch)` is called, that's why I don't have code for match request subsystem. I saw GKInviteEventListener protocol in the documentation, and it told me to use GKLocalPlayerListener instead, who's methods never being called. I also read this documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamekit/finding_multiple_players_for_a_game. And I still don't see how to deal with match request subsystem.

What is the right way to invite a friend and make the match?

Comment: All the code you've provided does is, effectively, launch an unknown view controller.    It shows little related to the mechanics of the match request subsystem that is causing problems, and therefore is very unlikely to let anyone answer your question.  You may want to revise the question with more relevant info...

Answer (score 0):

do not subclass GKMatchmakerViewController... in my case both my devices stayed on "connecting..." state for ever